# Is it possible to use "while something" instead of "while True" in this piece of code?

Tags: python, loops, printing, while-loop, try-catch

I've read on a few pages online that using "while True" and manually break the while loop with "break" is a bad practice. In this particular case, I'd like to not use "while True" and I wonder if it's possible.

```
while True:
    x = input()
    try:
        x = float(x)
        break
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

I've tried doing this:

```
while x is not float:
    x = input()
    try:
        x = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

But the loop never breaks. 
Is there a possible solution, or is it better to keep this as a "while True" loop?

Comment: You can replace `x is not float` with `not isinstance(x, float)`.

Comment: The problem with the second part is, if x were a float, you wouldn't need to try to type cast it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check if `x` is an instance of `float` or not, as per the suggestion by @Enzo

```
#Define x as None here
x = None

#Run loop until you find x which is a float
while not isinstance(x, float):
    x = input()
    try:
        #If x can be cast to a float, the loop will break
        x = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the entire loop, there's not much of a problem with using `break`. The main reason you should try to avoid `break` is because it can make larger loops or loops with more branches (`if`, etc.) inside hard to follow.

I don't think Python has a very simple way to do this, so a simple loop with `break` works well. The solution suggested in the other answers (using a placeholder value for `x`) works as well, but I personally find it less readable.

Answer (score 1):

From [PEP 315](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/) we have this statement:

> Users of the language are advised to use the while-True form with an inner if-break when a do-while loop would have been appropriate.

This statement refers to this part of the [PEP 315](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/):

> Subsequent efforts to revive the PEP in April 2009 did not meet with success because no syntax emerged that could compete with the following form:
>
> ```
> while True:
>     <setup code>
>     if not <condition>:
>         break
>     <loop body>
> ```

You don't cite the sources that claim this is "bad practice", but these excerpts from [PEP 315](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/) contradict them.